# Assign a function within a function

Tags: functions, assignment

What I'm doing wrong? 1st function works as expected but the 2nd one doesn't. What I want is to enter an algebraic expression and two numeric constants and get the same result as with the first function. Thanks in advance.

```
f[u_, v_] := Module[{g}, g[x_] := 3 x - 2; g[u] + g[v]]
f[2, 3]
(* 11 *)

h[m_, u_, v_] := Module[{g}, g[x_] := m; g[u] + g[v]]
h[3 x - 2, 2, 3]
(* -4 + 6 x *)
```

Comment: Some form of this question comes up a lot.  It's one of the more confusing aspects of the language.  I have marked your question as "already has an answer" pointing to three existing Q&A's that I believe you will find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[h1]
h1[m_, u_, v_] := Module[{g},
   g[y_] := Block[{x = y}, m]; 
   g[u] + g[v]]
h1[3 x - 2, 2, 3]
```

> 11

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[h2]
h2[m_, u_, v_] := Module[{g},
   g[y_] := m /. First[Cases[m, _Symbol, Infinity]] -> y; 
   g[u] + g[v]]
h2[3 x - 2, 2, 3]
```

> 11

```
h2[3 foo - 2, 2, 3]
```

> 11

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to fix my first answer**

*(I had some lingering definitions that misled me to thinking my first answer worked. Here's an update that should work)*

I think it would be better to include the independent variable explicitly in your function. For example:

```
h[m_, x_, u_, v_] := With[{g = Function[x, m]}, g[u]+g[v]]
```

*(The above definition gets a benign syntax warning about repeated symbols in a nested scoping construct. If this bothers you, you can use the equivalent alternative)*:

```
h[m_, x_, u_, v_] := With[{g = Function @@ Hold[x, m]}, g[u] + g[v]]
```

Then:

```
h[3x - 2, x, 2, 3]
```

> 11

On the other hand, we can repair your method by using [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate) and [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive) to get around the lexical renaming that happens with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed):

```
h[m_, u_, v_] := Module[{g},
    Activate @ Inactive[SetDelayed][g[x_],m];
    g[u]+g[v]
]
```

Then:

```
h[3x - 2, 2, 3]
```

> 11

Comment: @Sanmuten What is not working?

Comment: 1st example works but Mathematica issues a warning highlighting "x" variable in red. It reads as follows “ 'x' occurs twice in a nested scoping construct, in a way that is likely to be an error”. 2nd example works without issues.

Answer (score 1):

Change your approach: pass the function.

```
h2[g_, u_, v_] := g[u] + g[v]
h2[x \[Function] 3 x - 2, 2, 3]
```

If you are stuck with the expression, you can still do this:

```
xpr = 3 x - 2;
h2[x \[Function] Evaluate@xpr, 2, 3]
```